# Creating a SQL statement to return user ids that purchase multiple items

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure the solution is simple, but it evades me.

A table is configured like so:

```
TABLE NAME = sales
Field 1 = id INT Auto Increment Primary Key
Field 2 = user_id INT NOT NULL
Field 3 = item VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
```

So let's say I'm looking for users that have purchased the following items:

- ipod
- shoes
- bicycle

How would I structure a SQL statement to return the user_id values of users who have purchased the each of the three items (the user must have purchased all three items)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join up  views of the table for each item

Needs distinct as a user could buy many of one item.

```
select distinct(ipod.user_id )
from sales ipod
    inner join sales shoes on shoes.user_id = ipod.user_id 
    inner join sales bike on bike.user_id = ipod.user_id 
where ipod.item  = 'ipod' 
    and shoes.item = 'shoes'
    and bike.item = 'bicycle'
```

Comment: I like the way you structured the SQL.

Answer (score 4):

This method should make it easy to extend to other items too:

```
  select USER_ID, count(distinct ITEM)
    from SALES
   where ITEM in ('ipod', 'shoes', 'bicycle')
group by USER_ID
  having count(distinct ITEM) = 3
```

Comment: That works very well, except that I would change COUNT(*) to COUNT(DISTINCT ITEM), just in case a user bought the same item multiple times, which is a possibility in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be following.

```
select user_id
from sales s1
where exists (select user_id from sales s2 
               where item = 'ipod' and s2.user_id = s1.user_id)
and exists (select user_id from sales s2 
               where item = 'shoes' and s2.user_id = s1.user_id)
and exists (select user_id from sales s2 
               where item = 'bycycle' and s2.user_id = s1.user_id)
```

Comment: Works. In my case, I would probably do SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) so that I just had the id returned once.